# Java: JScrollPane JLabel too close to edge

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel, scrollpane

I have a jlabel inside of a jscrollpane using html to format it. The code is on github [here](https://github.com/lexware/Minecraft-Version-Installer/blob/ff220b136e8f2a05e32fdff421e29d3955ddb23d/src/malgm/minecraft/versioninstaller/ui/tabs/credits/CreditsInfoPanel.java) The problem is the text inside of both h1 tags is too close to the left even when aligned to the right. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
package malgm.minecraft.versioninstaller.ui.tabs.credits;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

import malgm.minecraft.versioninstaller.*;
import malgm.minecraft.versioninstaller.ui.TechUI;
import malgm.minecraft.versioninstaller.ui.controls.TiledBackground;

public class CreditsInfoPanel extends TiledBackground {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static ResourceFinder resFinder = new ResourceFinder();
    private Data data = new Data();

    public CreditsInfoPanel(ResourceLoader loader) {
        super(loader.getImage(resFinder.background()));

        BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(layout);

        // Welcome text
        JLabel text = new JLabel("<html>"
                + "<div align=\"right\">"
                + "<h1>" + data.getMVIName() +" build "+ data.getMVIBuild() +"</h1>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<center>"
                + "<h3>Development team:</h3>"
                + "<p>malgm (Jamie)</p>"
                + "<h3>Special thanks to:</h3>"
                + "<p>The Technic Team without them I wouldn't have this design.</p>"
                + "<p>Github for having such a wonderful service.</p>"
                + "<br />"
                + "</center>"
                + "<div align=\"right\">"
                + "<h1>" + data.getMMLName() +" build "+ data.getMMLBuild() +"</h1>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<center>"
                + "<h3>Development team:</h3>"
                + "<p>malgm (Jamie)</p>"
                + "</center></html>");
        text.setForeground(TechUI.COLOR_WHITE_TEXT);

        JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(text);
        s.setOpaque(false);
        s.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        s.setBorder(null);

        add(s, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

}
```

Comment: hi!  you should post your code here on SO.  that way there is a permanent record of it allowing this question to be useful in the future even if your project code changes or is deleted.

Comment: I have left a Github link.

Comment: i know that.  you missed my point.  how  will this question be useful in the future when you change your code or the project goes away?  Stack Overflow isn't here just so *you* get your question answered but as a repository of long lasting help.

Comment: Ok when Github starts working (I renamed the repository) I will post the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
`text.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15));`

Comment: Thanks after a quick edit to make it look right it worked! text.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 60, 15, 60));

Comment: after seeing the other answers i thought that i misunderstood the question but i'm glad it worked out fine for you :-)

Comment: the other answer changed the margin/border in HTML rather that Java. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [margin-left](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-left.asp)

```
"<div style='margin-left: 10px;'>"
```